# How to update stocks from supplier invoices in OpenERP 7?

Tags: odoo, stock, accounting

How can I automaticly update stocks whene I make a supplier invoice from Accounting module in OpenERP 7?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot update stock from supplier invoice. Create an incomming shipment. check the boolean field tobe invoiced, specify the partner,then confirm it and receive products. then create a invoice for it.